# Rails/Ruby. Searching for double emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an API in Rails 3.
Lately I have seen some user accounts being double. I am not sure how many so I need a way to find out which accounts that are double.

Is there a way, in ruby, to search the entire database and fetch those user accounts that got the same email address (hence double)?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the Rails console (`rails c`) and type something like this:

```
Account.group(:email).having('count_all > 1').count
```

This will return a Hash with email addresses being the key and the number of times it occured as the value.  The result will look something like this:

```
=> #<OrderedHash {"billyjoe@example.com"=>2, "johndoe@example.com"=>2}>
```

Then, I guess you could take those email addresses and actually get the accounts:

```
Account.where(:email => "billyjoe@example.com")
```

To output them all in the console, you could combine both of those like this:

```
email_hash = Account.group(:email).having('count_all > 1').count
email_hash.each do |email, count|
  Account.where(:email => email).each do |account|
    p account
  end
end
```

Comment: I get this error when running the first line in the console: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "count_all" does not exist
LINE 1: ...email AS email FROM "users" GROUP BY email HAVING count_all

Comment: What version of Rails are you on?  Also, it looks like you're using Postgres.  Is that right? You might try typing this first: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`  That will show you the SQL it's generating for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to use(for example):

```
UserAccount.all.group_by(&:email_address).each do |email, record|
 #you will get a set of records grouped by email address
end
```

this will help you (You did not write detailed description of your models but if think you will get the clue)